# Access 2010 Copy file from workstation to Server without override

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I am using Filecopy option to copy pdf and One files from a workstation to the server and it working good, but because there is too many files i want to copy just the new ones and not the existing.

This is my code:

```
   Dim LSQL, SOurce, DestinaTion, fILE As String

SOurce = "c:\mapping\"
DestinaTion = "\\rvfile03\Departments\Water\Common\FieldTickets\"
fILE = Dir$(SOurce & "*.one")
Do While Len(fILE) > 0
    FileCopy SOurce & fILE, DestinaTion & fILE
    fILE = Dir$()
    Loop
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the FileSystemObject first to make sure the file doesn't already exist:

```
Dim LSQL, SOurce, DestinaTion, fILE As String
Dim FSO

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

SOurce = "c:\xfer\"
DestinaTion = "c:\xfer2\"
fILE = Dir$(SOurce & "*.adp")
Do While Len(fILE) > 0
    If FSO.FileExists(DestinaTion & fILE) = False Then
        FileCopy SOurce & fILE, DestinaTion & fILE
    End If
    fILE = Dir$()
Loop
```

Comment: i tried it but it just not copying anything now. any suggestion?

Comment: @JOSELEON I think I see where the issue was, I was terminating the loop too soon with the check for FileExists.  Please see the updated code and let me know if it works for you.